# C debugging, #if DEBUG vs if (DEBUG)

Tags: c

First off: I am sorry if this question has been asked before. I'm an apt googler, but this really has me stumped and I can't find anything on it.

I am currently writing a small library and I'd like to implement debugging for it.
I'd also like to be able to turn the debugging completely off and the compiled code should not contain a single trace of there being debugging checks. I am using GCC and C99.

I know I can use:

```
/* Method 1, guaranteed good */
#define DEBUG 0
#if DEBUG
/* Do debugging here */
#endif
```

It gets the job done and there is not a trace of anything that happens between the if and endif, but I think this looks ugly. I have had some success with:

```
/* Method 2, seems to be valid */
#define DEBUG 0
if (DEBUG && value_to_check) { /* More debugging here */ }
```

For readability I much prefer method 2.

What I am wondering is if I am losing out on anything or if GCC will screw me over if I use method 2 over the tried and true method 1?

Comment: They're completely different, it's not a matter of readability. The preprocessor `#if` will cut out that text entirely before compilation. An `if` statement is compiled. Inside an `#if`, you can completely invalid C code, as long as the condition is false. Inside an `if`, the program still has to be valid. In practice, there's a good chance that they'll compile to the same assembly, but they're not the same concept.

Comment: It's supposed to be `#ifdef DEBUG`, in which case the second wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

difference is:

```
#if DEBUG
if(something_else)
{
    some_code
}
#endif
```

If `DEBUG` is not defined or its value is **0**, the next `if` and `some_code` will be not compiled and linked.

---

```
if (DEBUG && something_else)
{
   some_code
}
```

This will be compiled and very likely to be linked if your linker is not discarding the dead code. So better is to go the preprocessor way as it guarantees the absence of the debug code when the `DEBUG` symbol is not defined or has value of zero (false).

Comment: Who says it is compiled in the latter case? The condition in the if can be constant folded, the if will be known to be dead at compile time and as-if rule applies...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it will be compiled. Code may be discarded by some compilers - but it is implementation defined feature or extension. As far as I remember standard does not say anything about it

Comment: Hmm dammit Muphrys hits again. What I mean is that no one requires machine code be generated for the latter case. Then it is not even up to the linker.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but no one guarantees as well so it is better just to exclude it from the compilation

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The point is in '**optimized compiler**', that should mean the compiler works out the dead code. The standard itself shouldn't care for...

Comment: One of the advantages of the second method is precisely that the code is inspected and checked for validity, whereas with the `#if` / `#endif` method, the code to be eliminated is not checked for validity at all, and may suffer over time as the context changes.  So, where it can be used, the second method has advantages.  It can't be used at file scope, though — so you can't use the second method to eliminate global declarations or definitions. In particular, you can't eliminate a whole function using the second method. Personally, I wouldn't worry about the dead code not being optimized away.